# PHP Date Variable in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

The following query works fine when not using a variable for the date&time. However, I would like to use a variable for "2014-09-29 09:00:00".

```
    $query = '  SELECT *
                FROM dateTime1
                WHERE dateBooked="2014-09-29 09:00:00"';
```

(The "dateBooked" field is of datetime format.)

I below doesn't work:

```
$dateX = '2014-09-29 09:00:00';

$query = '  SELECT *
            FROM dateTime1
            WHERE dateBooked=' .$dateX;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your date:

```
$query = "  SELECT *
        FROM dateTime1
        WHERE dateBooked='" .$dateX . "'";
```

or

```
$query = "  SELECT *
        FROM dateTime1
        WHERE dateBooked='$dateX'";
```

Comment: oh sure answer the *easy* ones, like you NEED the rep points ;)

Comment: Lol. I was too busy today to be active here. It felt good to just to give an answer.

Comment: after 100k you should not be allowed to answer questions that don't require 3 phD's P)

Comment: Beauty! fastest answer I've ever had :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$dateX = '2014-09-29 09:00:00';
$query = '  SELECT *
                        FROM dateTime1
                        WHERE dateBooked="' . $ dateX . '"';
```